# JSON undefined field p5.js

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I'm having a really hard time, my mind just doesn't know what's going on here. I'm asking for help.
To be brief: I've got a JSON file:

```
{
    "animations":[
        {
            "x1": 3,
            "x2": 29,
            "y1": 4,
            "y2": 30
        },
        {
            "x1": 35,
            "x2": 61,
            "y1": 4,
            "y2": 30
        },
        {
            "x1": 67,
            "x2": 93,
            "y1": 4,
            "y2": 30
        },
        {
            "x1": 99,
            "x2": 125,
            "y1": 4,
            "y2": 30
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to access it on JS, I've got a live server running and my problem is that when I do

```
console.log (loadJSON(UFO.json));
```

it works just fine,everything is printed on the console, however, if I write

```
let data = loadJSON(UFO.json));
console.log(data[*fieldname*]
```

it says undefined.

EDIT:
This is the code that I tried

```
this.data = loadJSON(data_path);
//data_path is the path to the JSON file
```

If I print the this.data variable it shows the JSON file, however if I try accessing the animations field and afterwards any of the array positions it throws an error because the array (animations) is apparently undefined itself.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/p5-js-loadjson-function/) says to provide a `callback`. `loadJSON` is not likely synchronous and won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

@evolutionbox is somewhat right; the doco you've linked *does say* that you ought to use a callback. But it also says that the `loadJSON` function will return an object. The problem with relying on the return value of an asynchronous function like `loadJSON` is that the value may not be ready when you want to use it, and will return something like a blank `Object {}`. This is why you supply a callback; it'll be called *only* when the value is ready.

In case you don't understand what the callback parameter is you use it like this

```
function callback(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
  
loadJSON("UFO.json", callback);
```

Here the `e` argument to the `callback` function will be populated with the an object (the parsed JSON) from the `loadJSON` function.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your help. I think I was despaired, thanks man :D

Comment: No worries these things can be tricky : )